# Как добавить ReactJS к проекту AspNet?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Пытаюсь как тут добавить ReactJS к проекту, но при добавлении этой строки:

```
            app.UseReact(config => { });
```

Сам код в проекте

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWit
```

hViews();

```
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddReact();
        services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName).AddChakraCore();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseReact(config => { });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Проект перестает запускаться выдает ошибку:

```
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.
      Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpModule' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpModule' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
```

Но при отсутствии этой строки, ReactJS не запускается, как правильно добавить ReactJS?

Asp core 3.1

Comment: Обычно фронтенд и бекенд пишутся отдельными проектами. Почему вы решили их совместить в один?

Comment: @tym32167, Проект небольшой, не увидел смысла разделять, проект ради знакомства с ReactJS

Comment: Ради знакомства я бы наоборот начал с отдельного проекта, чтобы понимать как оно работает. Просто дотнетчиков, которые пишут на реакте в студии гораздо меньше, чем всех остальных, кто пишет на реакте. Потому мой вам совет - делайте отдельным проектом, настаивайте ноду, npm, потом create-react-app (или его версия с typescript) и вперед. Вам даже бекенд не особо нужен, берите json сервер и можете опыты ставить без проблем. Вам и студия не нужна, можете любимый блокнот поставить (я пользуюсь vscode) и работать в нем.

Comment: А сейчас вы боретесь с аспнетом, чтобы учить реакт - по мне так это просто потеря времени.